# 2 different ways to reverse an integer's digits - preferred way?

Tags: python

I'm grinding some LeetCode stuff, and one of the problems was to reverse an integer's digits (e.g. 123 becomes 321).

I thought of 2 ways to do it. The first is purely "numeric", using powers of 10 and modular arithmetic:

```
def reverse_digits1(num):
    reversed_num = 0

    while num > 0:
        reversed_num *= 10
        reversed_num += num % 10
        num = num // 10

    return reversed_num
```

The second way is to use built-in `str()` and `int()` methods.

```
def reverse_digits2(num):
    num = str(num)

    return int(num[::-1])
```

You essentially convert it to a string, reverse it, then return the reversed string as an integer.

Between these 2, which is the "better" way to do it? I'm guessing it's the first one, and it doesn't involve mutating numbers into strings and vice versa, and there is no potential loss of information? Would there even be a loss of information? The inputs are all integers, so there's no floating point numbers to worry about, right?

In general, is it a good idea to work with numbers through `str()` and `int()`, or should you just stick to "numerical methods"?

Comment: mm, this has been downvoted but I suspect there is an objective answer. The OP speaks of lost information so it's not necessarily opinion-based

Comment: I didn't realize this could be opinion-based, I genuinely thought 1 way was better than the other. Sorry!

Comment: Don't be sorry, I'm fighting your corner :) Doesn't mean that I'm right, only that people might be making a snap voting decision because you're asking something that, on the surface, is subjective. I'm not sure it is, though, overall.

Comment: what about negative numbers?

Comment: I like code (especially Python code) to be easily understandable. So I heavily prefer the second way. It fails for negative numbers, but this is easily fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added negatives just in case you may need them but the overall performance wouldn't change drastically without them either.

```
def reverse_digits1(num):
    if num < 0:
        neg = True
    else:
        neg = False

    if neg:
        num *= -1

    reversed_num = 0

    while num > 0:
        reversed_num *= 10
        reversed_num += num % 10
        num = num // 10

    if neg:
        reversed_num *= -1

    return reversed_num


def reverse_digits2(num):
    num = str(num)[::-1]
    if num.endswith('-'):
        num = '-' + num[:-1]

    return int(num)


from timeit import timeit as _t

timeit = lambda x: print(_t(x, globals=globals()))

timeit("reverse_digits1(123456789)")
timeit("reverse_digits1(-123456789)")
timeit("reverse_digits2(123456789)")
timeit("reverse_digits2(-123456789)")
```

This result in

```
5.207313711074936
6.272431325012982
2.453335871448827
3.285427497418125
```

So other than being more readable* it actually is also faster.

As of the information loss, I can't imagine it being possible with your regular integers,
and even if it was floats or some other type of number, strings would be more reliable since as a very basic example, 0.1+02 == 0.300000000000001, in strings however you can manipulate them with certain precision.

*Keep in mind, code is written to be read by humans.

Comment: I've `timeit`-ed it with a 10000-digit number -- the string version is ~70 times faster at this scale.

Comment: Yeah, bigger the number bigger the calculations while in strings it's merely the same job.